# Can't use globally defined custom attribute

Tags: android, attributes

So I have defined a custom attribute:

```
<resources>
   <attr name="filterColor" format="color"/>
</resources>
```

I did not declare it in an  to reuse it in other custom views.
However, I am not able to use it like so

```
<SomeView
    app:filterColor="@color/my_color"/>
```

Nor am I able to obtain it from AttributeSet

```
final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[]{R.attr.filterColor});
```

It's driving me crazy - why are we allowed to declare global custom Attributes then if we can't use them?

Comment: you can do both:  use it for some custom view in layout. xml and get its value via TypedArray,  why do you think you can't do that?

Comment: @pskink because it doesn't work - the editor (AndroidStudio) doesn't recognize the attributes (i can compile though). Also it crashes during inflation

Comment: my eclipse does recognize it and no runtime error when getting its value...

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, your XML appears to be missing the `<declare-styleable>` element:

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="ColorMixer">
    <attr name="color" format="color" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

(pulled from [this library project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer))

The `name` in `declare-styleable` should be the class name of the view that will use the attribute (`SomeView` in your case).

This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr).